# Apple Mail's "Remove Attachments" not removing attachments from hard drive

Tags: mail.app, email, attachments

I'm trying to slim down my email archive by removing attachments I no longer need, using the "Message > Remove Attachments" command in Apple Mail.

After removing several GB worth of attachments within Mail, I noticed that my ~/Library/Mail/ folder wasn't getting any smaller. Digging into the folder structure, I found that all of the attachments I had 'removed' from the emails are still present in the filesystem, deeply nested in the ~/Library/Mail/ folder.

I've tried quitting and restarting Mail, rebuilding the mailboxes, and restarting the computer, but the files remain.

**Are others experiencing this behaviour?** Is it possible to have the attachments removed from the hard drive when 'removed' from the email?

Running macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled onto a solution after several hours. Hopefully this can help others.

**Background**

I wanted to remove attachments larger than 1MB from emails older than 5 years. I made a smart mailbox with criteria for "has attachments" and "date recieved not in the past 5 years". I did a "select all" on the ~25k results and chose "Message > Remove Attachments" from the menu bar. Mail chugged away for half an hour, and afterwards the attachments were removed from the email messages, but the "Library/Mail" folder hadn't changed in size. Drilling into the "Library/Mail" folder structure in the Finder, I confirmed that the files were still there.

**The missing step**

I have my email sorted in folders in the Mail sidebar:

```
On my mac
     Project 1
     Project 2
     Etc
```

In order for the removed attachments to actually be deleted from the file system, ***I had to click on each folder in Mail's sidebar***. Something about opening the folder in Mail seemed to cause that folder's messages' removed attachments to be deleted from the file system.

**Important to mention that this was using a POP email account, and the messages were long ago deleted from the server, so there wasn't an issue of Mail re-downoading the attachments from the server.